# Array formula with Match and nested ifs

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested, match, array-formulas

So far I have used this to create a result over one column (formula lives son column X):

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(match($O$3:$O,'SheetB!C:C,0),"Sent","")))
```

Works well, simple trick as I add more data to SheetB!C:C i keep getting updates on the

Now I'm having trouble trying to nest an 'if' to check over another column if the first one doesn't give the a result:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(match($O$3:$O,'SheetB'!C:C,0),"Sent",if(match($P$3:$P,'SheetB'!C:C,0),"Sent","Not Sent")))
```

What wrong with this picture?

Comment: can you provide sample data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This more simple formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(match($O$3:$P,SheetB!C:C,0),"Sent","Not")))
```

gives the result in 2 columns:

```
Sent
       Sent
Sent
Sent
Sent
       Sent
```

---

If you like single column output, try using heavier formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(iferror(if(match($O$3:$O,SheetB!C:C,0),1,0))+iferror(if(match($P$3:$P,SheetB!C:C,0),1,0))>0,"Sent",""))
```

[My example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13p0RV-bH1FG81-5RyBJXS0ZYMCqMLQPN65YdGl7cGi8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I also suggest limiting arrays, so formula probably could work faster. Instead of `A2:A` use `offset(A2,,,counta(A2:A)`. This is good when range `A2:A` has no blanks inside